# How long does a ssh connection last?

Tags: ssh

I've been looking around StackOverflow and it seems that SSH connections will disconnect when it doesn't see any packets for a while (2 hours?).  Also, I looked in my `/etc/ssh/ssh_config` file and there doesn't seem to be anything there that would persist my current connection.

My question is: Even after 48 hours, why would an SSH connection persist? (my computer is turned off, but the server that I SSH to is presumably still online)

Comment: Looking in the wrong file, KeepAlive is in `sshd_config`

Comment: Actually, it may last forever.

Comment: Are you saying an ssh session persists after turning the client off?

Comment: I've had idle sessions on ssh last for weeks - theoretically it's infinite. This is provided that there are no timeouts on the shell (in bash it has `$TMOUT` as an example), `ClientAliveInterval` is not being used in the sshd, your network connectivity stays stable and your client IP remains static.

Comment: You say your "computer is off and your server is presumably online" So what gives you the impression that the ssh connection still exists?

Comment: I'm using VNC viewer to view the server and I don't need to do a SSH beforehand.

Comment: @JoelDavis Thanks very much, I found a 'TCPKeepAlive yes' in sshd_config! :)

Comment: I don't definitely know, nor can anybody here, depends on a lot of things, networking, host problems at either end, timeouts put in firewalls or even timeouts in shells.......so this really is a useless question without definitive answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you have to set ClientAliveInterval in your sshd_config.

Answer (score 8):

In theory, an SSH connection can last indefinitely.  It can be explicitly terminated by either side at the SSH layer (with a `FIN` packet) or abnormally terminated at the TCP layer (with a `RST` packet).

A `RST` can happen if one side sends a packet and doesn't get a TCP acknowledgement in a reasonable amount of time.  This usually happens because the other party is no longer there.  It could also happen if there is a NAT or firewall in between that has stopped keeping track of the connection (usually due to lack of activity), so that the two parties can no longer communicate.  More insidiously, a router at an evil ISP could inject `RST` packets into the connection, but such measures are usually reserved to content that the ISP finds objectionable, such as BitTorrent.

Keep-alives can help keep connections alive by reminding NATs or firewalls to maintain the connection state.  However, keep-alives can also hurt by making it more likely that a transient glitch in network connectivity would be noticed.